Beamer Page numbering with repetitive slides
I am using Beamer for a presentation and using \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number] to add in page numbering. However, I am using \item[]<1-> to add in items in itemize frame-by-frame. How do I get this total number of pages into the Beamer?

Please always include a short, but compilable test document in your questions.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yep sorry I'm in a rush, thank you for the quick help though :)

If you want to count the pages instead of the frames, you can use \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]:
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item test
  \item test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

